# Completion choices for bookmarks gone from Emacs minibuffer

Tags: emacs

I have a few bookmarks set up to jump to `dired` buffers. Previously Emacs would offer me a little (inline) list of candidates right there in the minibuffer after hitting `C-x r b` to recall the bookmark, but after some hacking of my `.emacs` file to split it into modules that list of candidates has disappeared.

I assume I've inadvertently changed some setting related to `ido` or `autocomplete`, both of which I use, but I can't work out what it is. Can anybody suggest a solution? [EDIT: The bookmarks do still exist and I can jump to them if I enter the name of the bookmark, but no prompt list. If I press TAB I get a buffer with completion candidates, but I don't get them in the minibuffer.]

[image: minibuffer]

and previously I would get this:

[image: minibuffer2]

I think it has to do with the following clump of functions that I copied from [Scott Frazer](http://scottfrazersblog.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/emacs-using-bookmarked-directories.html).

```
(require 'bookmark)

(defun my-ido-bookmark-jump ()
  "Jump to bookmark using ido"
  (interactive)
  (let ((dir (my-ido-get-bookmark-dir)))
    (when dir
      (find-alternate-file dir))))

(defun my-ido-get-bookmark-dir ()
  "Get the directory of a bookmark."
  (let* ((name (ido-completing-read "Use dir of bookmark: " (bookmark-all-names) nil t))
         (bmk (bookmark-get-bookmark name)))
    (when bmk
      (setq bookmark-alist (delete bmk bookmark-alist))
      (push bmk bookmark-alist)
      (let ((filename (bookmark-get-filename bmk)))
        (if (file-directory-p filename)
            filename
          (file-name-directory filename))))))

(defun my-ido-dired-mode-hook ()
  (define-key dired-mode-map "$" 'my-ido-bookmark-jump))

(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'my-ido-dired-mode-hook)


(defun my-ido-use-bookmark-dir ()
  "Get directory of bookmark"
  (interactive)
  (let* ((enable-recursive-minibuffers t)
         (dir (my-ido-get-bookmark-dir)))
    (when dir
      (ido-set-current-directory dir)
      (setq ido-exit 'refresh)
      (exit-minibuffer))))

;;define-key ido-file-dir-completion-map (kbd "$") 'my-ido-use-bookmark-dir)

(add-hook 'ido-setup-hook 'ido-my-keys)
(defun ido-my-keys ()
"Add my keybindings for ido."
(define-key ido-file-dir-completion-map (kbd "$") 'my-ido-use-bookmark-dir))
```

Comment: I have nerver had that list, but when I start typing a bookmark name I can complete it using the tab or the enter key. Out of personal interest, what theme are you using?

Comment: Hmm, if you've never seen it then maybe it was in a function that I added to my init file, but if so I can't find which function is responsbile. The theme is [`tangotango.el`](https://github.com/juba/color-theme-tangotango) which I'm using with Emacs 24.3's `load-theme` (used to use `color-theme` for this sort of thing but no more).

Comment: Is your config version controlled?

Comment: No, I don't think I have any conditions related to version in there.

Comment: What you show as a screenshot does not seem to correspond to the code you show. You are in `*scratch*`, not a Dired buffer, so the `dired-mode-hook` code is presumably irrelevant here. Hence also the `my-ido-bookmark-jump` code, which you don't seem to invoke either. It's not clear what you are actually doing, but it looks like you are just calling bookmark jump, to start with. Try to present the relevant code, tracing back from what key/command you actually call interactively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x r b")
    (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (bookmark-jump
       (ido-completing-read "Jump to bookmark: " (bookmark-all-names)))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. I thought I had included that keybinding but apparently I had missed it - just needed a smarter pair of eyes to look for it. Now it works again as per the second screenshot above.